# Solving system of non-linear equations (products of latent variables)

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I'm attempting to solve a system of equations in python, where each outcome is the sum of a series of products between two latent variables:

[image: Text]

where `i` and `t` take on many more values (e.g., 30 each) than `j` does (between 2 and 5). So if I and T took on 30 values and J took on 4, then there'd be 900 outcomes and 240 unknowns. I'd ideally like to solve for the values of gamma and eta in a least-squares sense. I know there needs to be some normalization.

Is this a standard problem with a canned function, or do i need to use a general minimization techniques?

Comment: I don't know of a standard solver that solves a problem of this form, but you can probably solve this using [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html).

Comment: Unless it's a difficult problem, scipy will do. If this gets huge scale and awful, you might need a commercial QP solver.

Comment: Are there bounds or constraints?

Comment: @reinderien no bounds. You’d have to constrain something otherwise there’s an infinite number of solutions (eg, scaling up all value of eta by 2 and down all values of gamma by 1/2 gives the same result), but I’m agnostic as to how the constraint is applied.

Comment: Since eta can vary across each i, you can’t set them all to 1 and get to the optimal. I think you could normalize by setting all etas for i=1 to one

Answer (score 0):

Recognize that your "sum of a series of products" is really just a matrix product.

The following doesn't produce a very good fit, but that may be because your problem is highly over-determined:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, check_grad
from numpy.random._generator import default_rng

I = 30
J = 5
T = 27

rand = default_rng(seed=0)
y = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(I, T))


def factors_from_flat(params: np.ndarray) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    gamma = np.resize(params[:I*J], (I, J))
    eta = np.resize(params[-J*T:], (J, T))
    return gamma, eta


def matrix_cost(gamma: np.ndarray, eta: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return gamma @ eta - y


def scalar_cost(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    gamma, eta = factors_from_flat(params)
    error = matrix_cost(gamma, eta).ravel()
    return error.dot(error)


def jacobian(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    gamma, eta = factors_from_flat(params)
    error = matrix_cost(gamma, eta)
    jac = np.empty(I*J + J*T)
    jac[:I*J] = (error @ eta.T).ravel()
    jac[-J*T:] = (gamma.T @ error).ravel()
    return 2*jac


x0 = np.full(I*J + J*T, 1/np.sqrt(I*J*T))
err = check_grad(func=scalar_cost, grad=jacobian, x0=x0)
assert err < 1e-2
    
result = minimize(fun=scalar_cost, x0=x0, jac=jacobian)
assert result.success, result.message

gamma_est, eta_est = factors_from_flat(result.x)
y_est = gamma_est @ eta_est
```

The Jacobian will happily point toward a minimum, and where that minimum might be local, that might be OK for your purposes. Predictably, this performs much better for data that have stripe patterns, as in

```py
y = rand.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(I, T))
y += rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=I)[:, np.newaxis]
```

or even biaxial stripes:

```py
y = rand.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(I, T))
y += rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=I)[:, np.newaxis]
y += rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=T)[np.newaxis, :]
```